# USB Headset not working propperly

Tags: sound, headset

I am using a USB Headset on ubuntu 14.10. The problem is that when I go to sound settings and test sound, if I click on front left I don't hear anything. But when I click on front right I hear front right in both ears.

- [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11881431/) is the output of `pacmd list-sinks`
- [Output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11881434/) of `pulseaudio --log-level=4 --log-target=stderr` (the last
  two lines are in red)
- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MblZY.png) of AlsaMixer, which also looks fine.

I also tried updating to a new kernel(v3.17.1-utopic), but it did not work.

Can anyone please help me fix this?

**EDIT**

It turns out that the problem was with the headset. I tried them on a windows pc an the problem was the same. I'm going to leave the question because it might help someone with another problem.

Comment: You seem to be in mono.

Comment: I am not in mono. I am in stereo. I checked it and I'm sure I'm in stereo.

Comment: But the _effect_ is such that it is in mono.

Comment: And is there a way to change that so i can hear both sounds. Because it's really annoying when i listen to music and i hear in both ears what should be in the right ear.

Comment: what is the output of `pacmd list-sinks` ? (with the headphone plugged in)

Comment: i edited the answer and added the output of `pacmd list-sinks` command. I hope it helps.

Comment: the configs there seems to be fine, what is the output of `pulseaudio --log-level=4 --log-target=stderr` ?

Comment: I added the output of `pulseaudio --log-level=4 --log-target=stderr` to the question.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of `alsamixer`? Also for me to get notified, you need to add `@daltonfury42` in your comments.

Comment: Try doing a `sudo service pulseaudio restart` after plugging the headphone in to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: @daltonfury42 i ran `sudo service pulseaudio restart` and this is what i got `stop: Unknown instance: 
pulseaudio start/running, process 6580`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25849/discussion-between-daltonfury42-and-beniamin-szabo).

Comment: If it's resolved and noone got the answer, you might want to remove the bounty...

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu's built in sound manager doesn't support USB headsets. I would recommend PulseAudio (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) over the default sound manager anyways just because of the ease of use.

Happy Travels!

Comment: i am using pulse audio already

Comment: @PieCrafted You are mixing several things up. pavucontrol is just another GUI for PulseAudio, configuring things there may help in some cases, but I'm not sure about this one here. That the default sound manager doesn't support USB headsets however is completely false.

Comment: My USB headset works fine. I use it for watching movies and talking in teamspeak. It's a crappy Turtle Beach P11. I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 and only told Ubuntu to use it as input/output device for sound other than that, I haven't changed any sound settings other than volume.